# Failed to deploy application

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, model-view-controller

When I am deploy application to AWS, in VS Output Console and in log.txt file is written that deploy is successfull, but when I go to console.aws it display error

[image]

```
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
```

Does anyone know, where this error comes from ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks, sorry to this. I didnt know that